# Validating a formset

Tags: django, formset

I am getting this error: `ValidationError at /screen-many/
[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']` and I think it is due to the folling code in my view...

```
# e_pk_list is a list of id's that I got from POST
e_students = Student.objects.filter(pk__in=e_pk_list)
my_iterator = iter(e_students) # Each list item will correspond to a form.
SurveyFormset = formset_factory(SurveyForm, extra=len(e_students))

# Is this the tampering that I can't do??
SurveyFormset.form = staticmethod(curry(SurveyForm, item_iterator=my_iterator))

if request.method == 'POST':

    survey_formset = SurveyFormset(request.POST)

    if survey_formset.is_valid():
        for form in survey_formset:
            saved = form.save(commit=False)
            saved.surveyset = ss
            saved.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
else:
    survey_formset = SurveyFormset()
```

Thanks

EDIT: I guess I should have mentioned that I already have a managementform in my template....

```
    <form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ survey_formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in survey_formset %}
            <div class="item">
              {% crispy form %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class='button' />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its seems that you didn't put `management_form` in your form .

Put this in your html form where your are displaying `SurveyFormset`

```
{{ SurveyFormset.management_form }}
```

Comment: Please bear in mind to put this string not inside a for-loop in case you are using one do display for fields. It should come right at the top of your formset

Answer (score 0):

A formset has many forms. Django keeps track of number of forms in formset using `management form data`. You should add `management_form` in the template too, which should be posted along with other POST data.

So, you should have:

```
<form method="POST" action=".">
    {{survey_formset.management_form}}
    {% comment %}Other form fields{% endcomment %}
</form>
```

Comment: I added my template code. I am fairly certain my problem is in the view, as I am getting POST data twice.